# Display icon next to text field

Tags: android, android-layout, mdc-components

I need to display an icon next to an text field like e.g. the person and phone icon in this screenshot ([source](https://material.io/components/text-fields/#usage))
[image]

Is there any component on Android for doing this or do I have to align both, icon and text field, manually in e.g. a constraint layout? Note that I need the icon next to the text field (like shown on the sreenshot), not inside of it.

Comment: There is a drawableLeft parameter, maybe works for you.

Comment: Based on assumptions from looking at the image, Im assuming you want a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, with an imageview and an edittext as children views.

Comment: According your Image, yes you have to do it manually and constraintLayout is the best option for you

Comment: NO there isn't any component on Android which adds icon next to TextInputLayout. You need to align an ImageView next to your InputLayout.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will work for you.

You can create the above layout using a `Relative Layout` or `Linear Layout`.

You need to take ImageView and Editext to create layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:contentDescription="Person Name"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Drawable Border:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#222222"></stroke>

    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"></corners>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not in the edit text field its in image view you can use imageview to set these icon before the textView and if you want to show the image into the textView you can use drawableSart into xml

Answer (score 1):

No there is no default component besides using the "drawable_left" attribute on an edittext. Which tends to never look as expected.

Currently best practice for this situation is to manually add an ImageView to the layout.

The general xml layout for a single input would look something like this. But there's more work to do to style the edittexts to make it look like the image.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using:

**Your Activity**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_phone" --> phone drawable
    android:tint="@color/gray"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:background="@drawable/et_style" --> this is custom drawable for EditText
    android:padding="20dp" />
```

**et_style.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">


<solid android:color="@color/white" />
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/gray" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this for EditText

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/card"
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste the following code into your xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPerson"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"></ImageView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/namePerson"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box_style"
            android:padding="8dp"></EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPhone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"></ImageView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.75"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:hint="Phone"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box_style"
            android:padding="8dp"></EditText>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/areaCode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box_style"
            android:padding="8dp"></Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For box style, copy paste the following code into a drawable xml file:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="1.5dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <corners
        android:radius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

Cheers. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no component with your desired specifics, the only way to achieve this is to manually align ImageView with the TextInputLayout. In my opinion, the best way to do it is using ConstraintLayout. 
You can read about ConstraintLayout [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

Answer (score 0):

There is no default component in Android like you mention in your snapshot but For that, you can try this way constraintLayoutTesting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPerson"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_storage"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgPhone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtNamePerson"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNamePerson"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_border"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spAreaCode"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgPerson"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="596dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_authentication"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtPhoneNumber"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgPerson" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_border"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgPhone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spAreaCode"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgPhone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgPhone" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spAreaCode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="596dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_border"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edtPhoneNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtNamePerson" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

round_corner_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Also, I have attached a screenshot of my testing code so you can get a better idea.

[image]